# How to update a table with certain fields?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, multiple-columns

I have a MySQL table with two copies (one in local server, one in web host) and I want to update **some** fields in my local server, than update **only** those values in my web host.
So say my table is like

Table in localhost, initially :

```
 id   username   money
---- ---------- -------
 1     user_01     0
 2     user2       0
```

Table in web host, initially :

```
 id   username   money
---- ---------- -------
 1     user_01   1000
 2     user2     2000
```

Than I want to change the `username` user_01  to *user1*, and update the web database, but **not** change the `money` field

Table in localhost, after change :

```
 id   username   money
---- ---------- -------
 1     user1       0
 2     user2       0
```

&

```
query -> ????
```

Table I want in web server, after change :

```
 id   username   money
---- ---------- -------
 1     user1     1000
 2     user2     2000
```

I tried to delete the table and create it from scratch but then the money value becomes 0, which I want to avoid.

So what query / type of export should I use (in phpMyAdmin or whatever) to update only certain fields?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it like this?

```
UPDATE  localhost
SET     username = 'user'
WHERE   username = 'user_01'
```

OR

```
UPDATE  localhost
SET     username = REPLACE(username, '_0', '')
WHERE   username LIKE '%\_0%'
```

- [expr LIKE pat [ESCAPE 'escape_char']](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: Yes, but I have multiple fields like this, and I update multiple rows, so I need a way to export the local table to the other one. I don't want to do all the updates again in the web server.